# Why isn't this ideal equal to $0$?

Tags: polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $I$ be a maximal ideal in $K[X,Y]$, where $K[X,Y]$ is the polynomial ring in two indeterminates over a field $K$. I would like to prove that at least one of $I \cap K[X]$ and $I \cap K[Y]$ is not equal to the zero ideal.

I think that if $I \cap K[X]=I \cap K[Y]=0$, then this assumption causes a contradiction with $I$'s maximality. However, I can't prove it.

Would you have any hints or ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you found an example where one of them is zero?

Comment: This would mean that $x,y$ are transcendental over $K$ in the field $K[x,y]/I.$ Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Sorry, I do not have found such examples.

Comment: Your conclusion is that at least one of $x,y$ is algebraic over $K$ in the field $K[x,y]/I.$ But if one is algebraic, then both are algebraic, unless the idea is really simple, like $I=\langle q(x)\rangle$ where $q$ is the minimal polynomial for $x.$ But then $I$ is not maximal, so because we can add $x$ to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated due to comment below from Lukas Hager.]

This follows from the [Zariski Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma). Zariski says that any finitely-generated field extension is a finite(-dimensional) extension.

You actually get that $I\cap K[x]\neq 0$ *and* $I\cap K[y]\neq 0.$
Even more generally, for any non-constant $f(x,y)\in K[x,y],$ $I\cap K[f(x,y)]\neq 0.$
Since $I$ is maximal, $k=K[x,y]/I$ is a finitely generated field extension of $K,$ and thus finite-dimensional.

If $n$ is the dimension, and $\overline x$ is the image of $x$ in $k,$ then $1,\overline x,\overline x^2,\dots,\overline x^n$ are not linearly independent over $K,$ so for some non-zero $q(x)\in K[x],$ $q(\overline x)=0$ But that means $q(x)\in I.$

This proves the same for maximal ideals of $K[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m]$ for any $m.$ Indeed, Zariski's Lemma is equivalent to this general case.

Of course, if this were an exercise before knowing Zariski, this answer would be inadequate without also proving Zariski...

---

**My Original Post**

Not an answer, but we can show that if $I\cap K[x]\neq 0$ then $I\cap K[y]\neq 0.$

Let $k=K[x,y]/I$ be the quotient. Since $I$ is maximal, $k$ is a field extension of $K.$ Let $\overline x,\overline y$ be the images of $x,y$ in $K.$

Since $I\cap K[x]$ is an ideal in $K[x],$ if it is non-zero, let there is an irreducible $q(x)\in K[x]$ such that $q(\overline x)=0$ in $k.$ So $\overline x$ is algebraic over $K.$

If $I= \langle q(x)\rangle,$ then $I$ is not maximal, because we can find a bigger ideal, $\langle q(x),y\rangle.$

So some $f(x,y)\in I$ is not divisible by $q(x).$

Write $f$ as a polynomial in $K[x][y],$ so $$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_{i}(x) y^i.$$

Then not all the $a_i(x)$ are divisible by $q(x),$ so $g(y)=f(\overline x,y)$ is a non-zero polynomial in $K[\overline x][y],$ and $g(\overline y)=f(\overline x,\overline y)=0.$

So $\overline y$ is algebraic over $K(\overline x)$ and $\overline x$ is algebraic over $K,$ so $\overline y$ is algebraic over $K,$ and thus some non-zero $p(y)\in I.$

---

This means that your statement is equivalent to the statement:

> If $I$ is a maximal ideal in $K[x,y]$ then $K[x,y]/I$ is a finite  extension of $K.$

Comment: The statement that you reduced the question to is an instance of Zariski's lemma.

Comment: @LukasHeger Ah, my commutative algebra is rusty, and was trying to get a "basic" proof. It's easier to prove the result the OP wants directly from Zariski, I guess.

Comment: If one takes Zariski's lemma for granted, this is the "canonical" proof.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be maximal such that $\mathfrak{m} \cap K[X] =0$, then $x$ (which I'll use as notation for the class of $X$ in $K[X,Y]/\mathfrak{m}$, same for $y$ and $Y$) is transcendental over $K$.

Case 1: $y$ is transcendental over $K(x)$, then we have that $K[X,Y]/\mathfrak{m}$ contains both $K(x)$ and $K(y)$. But $K[X,Y]/\mathfrak{m}$ is generated as an algebra by $X$ and $y$, so we get that $K[X,Y]/\mathfrak{m}=K(x)(y)=K(x,y)\cong K(X,Y)$

Case 2: $y$ is algebraic over $K(x)$, so $K[X,Y]/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite extension of $K(x)$.

I claim that in both cases, $K[X,Y]/\mathfrak{m}$ is not finitely generated as a $K$-algebra, which is a contradiction. In the first case, this is easy: there are infinitely many irreducible polynomials in $K[X,Y]$, so considering the collection $\{\frac{1}{p}\}$, where $p$ runs over the irreducble polynomials gives the result.

In the second case: Apply the [Artin-Tate lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Tate_lemma) (which has a short and elementary proof, see the link), to see that $K(x) \cong K(X)$ is a finitely generated algebra. As in the first case, there are infinitely many irreducible polynomials in $K[X]$, so the same argument gives a contradiction.